# Offline Map Service with Mapnik and Leaflet

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, leaflet, mapnik, offline

I'm relatively new to GIS, so I hope my asking doesn't appear to be ignorant in any way.

I currently work on an offline map service solution for usage in areas without internet connection. For that purpose I want to download the data from a provider (i.e. geofabrik.de), load it into a PostGIS enabled database by using osm2pgsql, process the data with Mapnik and store the rendered tiles on the local machine. The map data doesn't need to be up-to-date but should be able to get updated once or twice a year.

From there, Leaflet will be used to display the rendered tiles and also satellite tiles if possible, as a slippy map. The map user should also be able to edit data on the map and to save them as vector layer to the database.

[image]

I already did something similar by using Geoserver, GeoWebCache and OpenLayers but I'd like to have at least two approaches for comparison.

My questions are:

- Where is the difference in using Mapnik or Geoserver? This may seem to be a redundant question but I couldn't answer it - so far.
- Where do I get the satellite tiles? I read something about OSM providing servers for them but only give out higher capacity downloads to chosen projects.
- Are there any performance issues I should look out for? The provided systems are old Panasonic Toughbooks with limited CPU and RAM. I already tried the Geoserver way on them. It worked, since there is no real-time rendering. But maybe I'm overlooking something.
- Any flaws with the approach?

Thanks for investing time in this!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach looks ok to me. On my local system, I skipped the TileCache part. Mapnik fills the folders in the way Openlayers reads them from disk using file:///... I don't know if leaflet can do it the same way.

For the satellite tiles: You have no chance to get them legally. Google and bing do not like storing their tiles locally. If you have mapnik-rendered tiles form OSM, they will be not transparent, so you will not see the satellite picture underneath.

If performance is an issue, you can render on a faster machine, and copy the tiles to slower ones for the end user.

I have not tried storing data back into the database.

Comment: Thanks for answering. For the performance issues I'll probably go the pre-render way on a fast machine.

Comment: Providing the tiles without TileCache works without problems. Had to use file:///C:/osm_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

Answer (score 2):

For the satellite tiles, you could render them yourself using Mapnik.  [Landsat](http://landsat.usgs.gov/) and [NAIP](http://www.fsa.usda.gov/FSA/apfoapp?area=home&subject=prog&topic=nai) are two sources of free satellite raster data.

**edit**: I've also just come across a growing dataset (also free) of [High Resolution Orthoimagery](http://nationalmap.gov/ortho.html), which I've never used, but is much higher detail than the other two sources.

Comment: This looks promising! Thanks for your answer. I'll play around with it.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how confident you are with technical setups, rather than running local GeoServers, you could use something like [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) to generate MBTiles files of all your images, or just the images using [Invar](https://github.com/onyxfish/invar/).  This can then be show by simple python code like [TileStache](http://tilestache.org).  This would be a much lighter weight setup.

Comment: Had a look on TileStache. Seems to be very promising. In fact I rendered tiles for the zoom levels 0 - 18 for a small space in Germany. It's already 23 GB on disk. The MBTiles is more than half the size of it!