# Offline map with less zoom size and maximum area covered

Tags: google-maps, maps, mobile, offline

I am developing a mobile app for which an offline map is required. Is it possible to have such map within few 10s of MBs? The requirement is to have:

1. Map with smaller zoom size; e.g. In this URL of Google Maps, the
   **`z`** denotes the zoom size (following longitude, latitude): https://www.google.co.in/maps/@12.9677753,77.6490654,15z; Hence 15
   Google Map equivalent zoom size is manageable, I am ok with 14 as
   well if it reduces the size considerably
2. The map can be a big image file with names of the street etc.
   printed
3. The map should cover at least a country as big as US/Canada (if not
   the whole world)

Google maps doesn't seem to help. I also tried [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) and its various [links](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) but what I found was the map size of 30-40 GB. I referred following question as well, but unable to get answer:
[Offline Map Service with Mapnik and Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107639/offline-map-service-with-mapnik-and-leaflet)

From where can I download such small size map or what is the minimal size of map which has bare minimal street view (not sure if [this link](ftp://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/misc/openstreetmap/download.openstreetmap.de) can help)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can get the map that small and still be readable like at that zoomlevel.

Just consider this:

- the scalebar on gmaps (bottom right corner) is roughly 1", so even at z14: 1 km = 1 inch
- an imaginary country with 1000km*1000km, so a map of that country would take 1000"x1000" (1000000)
- you want it colored, so at least 8bit, i.e. *8
- you want to identify objects *within* that 1km (=1"), so you can't use 1dpi .. let's take 50dpi, so *50

now we are at 1000000 * 8 * 50 =~ 50MB

what do we get for our 50MB?

- 256 colors (might be enough for a street-map)
- 50dpi, which isn't close to readable
- a 1000*1000km country (as comparison: canada is ~5500km*4500km)

Comment: +1 thanks. Is it possible at least to **download** all the co-ordinates against the addresses in the world or a given country in simple text format. Using Google API, it takes too much of time. e.g., if we run Google API then 1 big city is covered in 3 hours, with .001 precision. (i.e. AB.XYZ, AB.XYZ format); This is too slow and I believe all these data should be stored somewhere ready made for quick download.

Comment: Both, detailed Map-/Sat-Images and georeferenced Adresslists are a **big** Business. I don't think there is a way to get them (legally) for free.

Comment: Is it not possible through the free sites like [OpenStreetMap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStreetMap#Usage) or [blueblackworks](http://www.blueblackworks.com/)? I tried their FTP server, but couldn't find it in a downloadable way.

Comment: You can download a full copy of the OSM Database [here](http://planet.openstreetmap.org/) and extract all building nodes ... but OSM is _nowhere near_ complete. As example: in Austria are roughly 2.7M registered buildings (i.e.: with street/houseno.). According to the latest [Analysis](http://osm.lyrk.de/elementauswertung) OSM contains about 600k of them. So just 1/4 in a - more or less - high active area.