# How/Where to get reverse geocodes up to 5 decimal points precision for offline use?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, offline

I would like to have a simple text file(s) with following reverse geo-codes information for all the countries (i.e. world):

> Coordinates -- Address

e.g.

> 12.96779, 77.65306 -- #7, Jeevan Bima Nagar Main Rd, 10th Main, DOS Colony, New Thippasandra, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560075, India

First I tried to call Google maps API, but it has its limitation of number of API calls per day. In case of OSM, there is no such limitation but at .00001 precision, it will take several years to get just 1 square degree!

We downloaded `planet.osm` (550 GB after extration) and `planet.osm.pbf` for offline database/server creation. However, we are unable to find a way out of it to re-create the server locally and make the API calls which will be fast enough.

**Is it possible to get/purchase such reverse geo-codes of near Google-Maps like accuracy for our offline usage?**

Otherwise, is there a full proof link which teaches, how to create a OSM like local server out of .osm or .osm.pbf? (Have tried many of them so far, but no success)

[Note: Previously I had asked [slightly related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137869/offline-map-with-less-zoom-size-and-maximum-area-covered)]

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me. Do you just want a database with world-wide addresses and corresponding coordinates? Or all geographic coordinates in steps of .00001 degrees with their corresponding addresses? The latter would be roughly 3 billion entries, most of them pretty useless.

Comment: @scai, later would be better (i.e. reverse geo-codes), as I can optimize the unwanted addresses. However, if the former is available (i.e. geo-codes) is also good assuming that it covers all the addresses possible. Is there any such database or way to retrieve that?

Comment: The former is implicitly contained in OpenStreetMap. Try to get familiar with OpenStreetMap's data model, i.e. [elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) and [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) until you continue reading about how [addresses](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Addresses) are represented.

Comment: @scai, as a team we tried lots of options by using various tools. It seems less support for latest versions of some of the pkg. Our intention was to setup OSM locally and get reverse geocodes.

Comment: If you have problems setting up a local OSM database then please ask a separate question about this new issue.

Comment: If you want to purchase any OSM related services about geocoding, see the OSM wiki about http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Commercial_OSM_Software_and_Services or http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines ...  At least mapbox.com, MapZen, Mapquest and komoot have some nice tools that maybe can run on your own servers.